# Composer check local repository instead online repository like Maven

Tags: php, composer-php

how to get composer http://getcomposer.org to work like maven in java. Instead of getting repository online, it can get from local repository. So, we don't have to download again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Maven, but at least two options in composer's world come to my mind:

**Access a local git repository**

Let's say you want to use a local git repository of braincrafted's bootstrap bundle.
Add the following entry to your composer.json:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "/home/user/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle"
    }
]
"require":{
     "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle":"dev-master"
}
```

**Satis**

Another alternative is Satis - makes you have your private packagist.com
It's explained in the [documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md)

This talk is worth watching to learn more about Composer, SAtis etc: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3NwF8RV1lY

Comment: I think it's not the right answer for me but it's really helpful. Thank you :D